# Can [diacritic] and [diacriticals] be made synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[diacriticals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diacriticals) has only one question, and [diacritic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diacritic) has at least a few more. I think they should be made synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather make [diacriticals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diacriticals) a synonym of [diacritic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diacritic), and merge the tags.